# Android - get httpPost string

Tags: android, string, http-post, httprequest

I am making HttpPost requests to distant server. When the server is inaccessible, I want to store prepared request (it has form of HttpPost) into SharedPreferences or database. Question is, do you know how to store HttpPost into String and save it? Up to now, I have not been able to transfer HttpPost into String. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can store parameters that you want to pass to server instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a class that implements [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), store all the necessary data for the HttpPost in there and the persist this class using [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).